# How to update database with AJAX & Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

### UPDATED QUESTION:

I want to update a database table column with **AJAX** and **Laravel 5.2** framework. I have a button `Delier` when i will click on that button then it will update a column from `Not Shipped` to `Shipped`. I also using **[sweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)** plugin for popup styling. I have searched a lot. But i didn't find perfect procedure of it. I have tried this way:

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/winner/status/{id}', ['as' => 'winner.status', 'uses' => 'WinnerController@statusUpdate']);
```

**WinnerController:**

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $winner = Winner::find($id);
    $winner->product_stat = "Shipped";

    $winner->save();
    $request->session()->flash('alert-info', 'Product Status Updated!'); 
    return Redirect::to('admin/winner/detail');
}
```

**Script in View:**

```
$(".action-button").click(function(){    
swal({
  type : 'warning',
  title: 'Submit what you want',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  allowOutsideClick: false

}).then(function (text) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : '',
    success: function(data){
        swal('Confirmed!','success')
    }

  });
})

});
```

**Blade:**

```
@foreach($dataQrDetails as $dataQr)
    <tr>
        <td> {{  $dataQr->product_name }} </td>
        <td> {{  $dataQr->product_stat }} </td>
        <td> {{  $dataQr->created_at }} </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs action-button" href="{{route('winner.status',$dataQr->id)}}">Delier</a></td> 
    </tr>                            
@endforeach
```

**Blade frontend:**

[image]

This is updating column but after updated its redirected another page and its showing just popup its not need to submit confirm button of popup. Is there anyway to do this? Please could anyone answer my below question:

> - What will be the best procedure to using AJAX with Laravel.
> - What will be route call for update data?
> - How i define AJAX url?

Comment: what is this `{{url('admin/winner/status/')}}" + {{$id}}` ?? You're doing Update(save) is it ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I want to update. How i declare the method url so that if anyone click on buttton then method will be call and update database.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I am waiting for an answer thanks.

Comment: check the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser

best ways to pass variable in ajax request in laravel]

your route is

```
Route::get('testUrl/{id}', 'TestController@getAjax');
```

ajax request

```
<script>
  var Id = <?php echo $id; ?>
    $(function(){
       $('#button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testUrl/{id}',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: Id },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#something').html(response);
                }
            });
       });
    });    
</script>
```

TestController.php

```
public function getAjax()
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    return $id // any value return as a response 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is do here is, when you load the form I'll save the user id in Hidden field and when i submit will pass that to controller as well

**In Form**

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
```

**In AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/update-winner",
    type:'POST',
    data: {_token:_token, id:id, .....},
    success: function(data) {
        if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
            swal('Confirmed!',data.success); # or swal('Confirmed!','success')
        }else{
            swal('error!',data.error); # or swal('error!','Errorrrrr')
        }
    }
});
```

**In Route**

```
Route::post('update-winner','HomeController@statusUpdate');
```

**In Controller**

```
function statusUpdate()
{

    <!-- if need  -->
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        /....
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails())
    {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $request->input("id");
        $winner = Winner::find($id);
        $winner->product_stat = "Shipped";

        $winner->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 01**

In delete button add this `data-delete="{{ id_fiedld_name}"`

and in Ajax you can catch

```
var id = ($(this).data('delete'));
```

Comment: I am trying your procedure and let you know. Again i don't have any form here. I just click on a button and status update. Will i create a hidden form?

Comment: Check my frontend view (updated questions)from where i will update product status. There is no form here. After clicking button i will update status one by one.

Comment: Updated my questions. Its working for updating without ajax. How i implement this.

Comment: Will keep `href="{{route('winner.status',$dataQr->id)}}"` ? why i need `var id`? It updated so i think i just ajax call. I can get id from `$dataQr->id` so i think no need to generate id. I just need after confirmation of popup then data will be updated.